# Spring: NotWritablePropertyException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

*applicationContext*

```
<bean id="contentRegisteringBean" parent="abstractRegisteringBean" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="processor">
        <bean class="com.somepackage.ContentService$Processor"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="abstractRegisteringBean" class="test.spring.MockFactoryBean">
    <property name="type" value="com.somepackage.ProcessorRegisteringBeanImpl"/>
</bean>
```

*ProcessorRegisteringBeanImpl*

```
public class ProcessorRegisteringBeanImpl {
    private Processor mProcessor;


    public Processor getProcessor() {
        return mProcessor;
    }

    public void setProcessor(final Processor processor) {
        mProcessor = processor;
    }
}
```

*MockFactoryBean.java*

```
public class MockFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {
    private Class<T> type;

    public void setType(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return Mockito.mock(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getObjectType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

> org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'processor' of bean class
>   [test.spring.MockFactoryBean]: Bean property 'processor' is
>   not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type
>   of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: What is `MockFactoryBean`?

Comment: @axtavt look at updated question pls

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a `FactoryBean`, Spring expects that you configure properties of the `FactoryBean` rather than properties of the object it creates.

Try the following instead:

```
<bean id="contentRegisteringBean" parent="abstractRegisteringBean" lazy-init="false">
    <!-- Define concrete class to pass to Mockito.mock() -->
    <constructor-arg value = "com.somepackage.ProcessorRegisteringBeanImpl" />

    <property name="processor">
        <bean class="com.somepackage.ContentService$Processor"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Abstract definition of beans created using Mockito.mock() -->
<bean id="abstractRegisteringBean" abstract = "true"
     class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method = "mock">
</bean>
```

Comment: pls more explanation. Why?